# Field.Store.COMPRESS in Lucene 3.0.2

Tags: lucene

I am upgrading lucene 2.4.1 to 3.0.2 in my java web project
in lucene API's i found that Field.Store.COMPRESS is not present in 3.0.2 so
what i can use in place of Field.Store.COMPRESS?
some time field data is so large that i have to compress that.

Answer (score 10):

Lucene made the decision to not compress fields, as it was really slow, and not Lucene's forte. The Javadocs [say](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Store.html):

> Please use
>   CompressionTools instead. For string
>   fields that were previously indexed
>   and stored using compression, the new
>   way to achieve this is: First add the
>   field indexed-only (no store) and
>   additionally using the same field name
>   as a binary, stored field with
>   CompressionTools.compressString(java.lang.String).