# Error On Item Saving-Field not found: 'Store.COMPRESS'

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm getting the "***Field not found: 'Store.COMPRESS'***" error when I try to save item.

Earlier I was getting Lucene version error of ***Lucene version 2.9.4.1*** ,so I updated the following setting in ***web.config***:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Lucene.Net" publicKeyToken="85089178b9ac3181"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.9.4.0" newVersion="3.0.3.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

to

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Lucene.Net" publicKeyToken="85089178b9ac3181"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.9.4.1" newVersion="3.0.3.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

-Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store.COMPRESS is a Lucene 2.x feature that is no longer supported in 3.x.  Your assembly redirect bindings only fixes the bindings, not the actual implementation of Lucene.

Looks to me like you have Lucene 2.x code running in your solution; it will need to be upgraded/rewritten for Lucene 3.x.

Javadoc for Field.Store: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Store.html

Note that it now lists as deprecated.

SO Post here: [Field.Store.COMPRESS in Lucene 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426576/field-store-compress-in-lucene-3-0-2)

Comment: Hi Mark,

I've not written any code which implements lucene yet & it's happening only if I update the Presentation of the item.
Also in logs,I'm getting following error when I save item:

`Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Comment: Well someone has :-)    Likely there is some custom indexing code in your solution, tied in to item:saved handlers or similar. If you remove the binding you posted above, you will get errors listing the assembly that requires Lucene 2.x. That will be your first clue, on where to look for answers.

Comment: And your SQL error message is not related to the Store.COMPRESS error message this post is about. Likely this is something else in your environment.

Comment: As you suggested I updated the assembly bindings to be default one & then getting error like [this](http://snag.gy/EJRo4.jpg).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see the full stack trace in that image. If I were to guess a bit, problems related to Lucene would normally occur if the Sitecore solution had been upgraded recently. Like from pre-6.5 to 6.6 or 7.x - and you might still have bespoke Lucene code in your solution. This could be code written, but could also be indexing code from a non-updated Sitecore module - WeBlog or somesuch. You will get an indicator of which assembly requires the outdated Lucene version at the very bottom of your stack trace

Comment: Ok. So your solution is configured to invoke Sitecore.Search.SearchManager on item:save (see the call to Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration right above Sitecore.MainUtil.RaiseEvent). Which version of Sitecore are you on?  Because this looks like the "traditional" indexing code in "aging" Sitecore solutions. It is possible your Lucene version SHOULD be 2.x, and has been upgraded for other reasons.

Comment: Yes you are right,this solution was upgraded from 6.6 to 7.2, & We didn't remove old 'Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.config' from include's folder.

-Thanks